# Using a DataType from unreferenced dll works in XAML, why?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, c++-cli

I have dll A and B which are both written in C++Cli.
Both A and B have namespaces SomeNamespace.MyNamespace.
I have C# Application compiled as class library I'm calling dll C.
A references B and C, and C references B.

Now, in one of the XAML resources in dll C.  I have declared the following:

```
xmlns:myNamespace="clr-namespace:SomeNamespace.MyNamespace;assembly=A"
```

This gives me access to the data types in A even though A is NOT referenced. So, I'm able to do the following:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myNamespace:SomeClassFromA}">
    <TextBlock Text="This works!"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Should I continue using this? Any potential issue(s)?

**Edit**

I ran into this by accident.  It seems like a hack, so I posted a question here.  Currently, I'm using interfaces and each classes from A has a string property DataTemplateKey to know which DataTemplate it uses. However, if I can reliably use this without this breaking in future versions of .Net, it would make my current code a lot cleaner.

**Edit 2**

I'm now getting a compile-time error: The type reference cannot find a public type named  ...

So, now it doesn't work.

Comment: How should i tell you what the unforeseen consequences are if the are *unforeseen*?

Comment: Fair enough. Unforeseen by me.

Comment: Any particular reason for the down-vote.  Is this not a valid question?

Comment: Would referencing A cause errors?

Comment: Yes, circular dependencies.